# Reconciling keeping up with tzibbur, and not making a hefsek

Tags: tefilla, hefsek-interruption, tefillah-betzibbur

If one reaches the end of Pezukei Dezimra, for example, one often waits for the shaliyach hatzibur to get to where you are up to, and sing Yishtabach with them. This is one example among many where I have seen conflicting opinions about what to do. Some examples may be worse than others, like not interrupting between Geula and Tefilla, and saying Amida with the tzibbur.

On the one hand it is praised to say certain things together, to sing together, to not be poresh min hatzibur, as well as the fact that it seems to be the norm everywhere I daven.

On the other hand, in normal circumstances it's not permissible to pause in the middle of a bracha, especially not for longer than a second or so. I've been told by one of my maggid shiurs not to do it (it was specifically about Pezukei Dezimra in that case).

All these years I've wanted to know what the shak ve'tariya is for this point, but have never found any sources that discuss it in these terms. Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: Can you say your silent part slower?

Comment: I can, but this is not a personal question. Assuming one can go slower, what is the halacha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When discussing the end of *pesukei dezimra*, [Mishnah Berurah 53:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.53.3?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=bi) writes that an individual who is waiting for the *chazzan* should recite *yishtabach* himself and only then wait for the *chazzan*, rather than waiting before *yishtabach*.

Comment: yes, even on Shabbos!

Comment: Thank you. Any sources to support making the hefsek if it means completing with the tzibbur anyone knows about?